# How to multi-process a for loop looping over through every pixel in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have code looping through ever pixel:

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        print("do something")
```

How would I use multi-processing to speed up performance?

Comment: From other posts and my experience, dividing the work on a per-pixel basis will very likely reduce performance (unless your 'do-something' is very compute-intensive).  However, if you have a batch of pictures then you could increase performance by assigning a worker/task to each picture.

Comment: my do something is a raytracer

Comment: Checkout [My Notes on Optimizing a Python Raytracer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/e4mv0n/my_notes_on_optimizing_a_python_raytracer/)

Comment: Thanks! Looks helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing by hand isn't easy, you have to rule threads, shared resources amd synchronization, the GIL.

I assume the `print` is a joke and I suggest you to look at numba
http://numba.pydata.org/

Pure number crunching routines are optimized a-la-carte, example

```
@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def simulator(out):
    # iterate loop in parallel
    for i in prange(out.shape[0]):
        out[i] = run_sim()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "by hand"?

Comment: I mean to develop you solution instead of using a framework like numba. How many hours will you spend coding? What about the performance?